# 'We communicated a few weeks ago' in an Email

Tags: phrases, expressions, email, letter-writing

I am writing an email that has not to be formal. I am trying to translate a phrase from Spanish that goes: 'Nos comunicamos hace unas semanas.' The literal translation would be 'We communicated a few weeks ago' and I am trying to use that phrase to let the receiver know that we were in touch before, and I am re-approaching her to solve something.

I wanted to know if that sounds right and natural or is there another common way to let the other person know that we were in touch before, and use that as an introductory phrase.

Comment: Have you seen [interpersonal.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Hey, @marcellothearcane. I am just asking if that sounds normal and natural in English since I am directly translating from Spanish. Sometimes expressions can not be translated, so I wanted to know if that could be a regular phrase/expression to use, and then start writing the gist of the letter.

Comment: That's fine, I'm not shoving you off there! Just thought you might be interested after reading this question - it's in beta stages and needs support :)

Comment: Oh, alright! @marcellothearcane ;)

Comment: *We communicated a few weeks ago* is not the   literal translation of Spanish sentence.

Comment: @Clare so what is it?

Comment: Something like *We communicate makes some weeks*. A literal translation is word for word.

Comment: @Clare really? You forgot the past tense in 'communicate'. And 'hace' in that sentence is an impersonal verb, and when it refers to time it translates to 'ago'. Find a dictionary and check that. The only word you could say I put extra was 'few', but when I say 'unas' I do not mean a lot. I encourage to give an answer to the post, too, I am not the only one evaluating what people post

Comment: Yeah, you can't really have a word for word translation of that sentence; the two languages are different, work differently. *hace* meaning *ago* is not a literal translation.

Comment: Anyway, *We communicated a few weeks ago* is fine for business correspondence, which these days seeks clear, natural language; not the business stilted language of last century, such as *Further to our communication...*

Comment: Last, frankly I don't know if your question is on-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks, @Clare... what about _We were in touch a few weeks ago_? Does that make sense in English? If it does, I guess it has the same meaning.

Comment: I myself would probably be more specific and name *how* (by what method) "we communicated". We talked on the phone, or we exchanged emails on some subject... But that's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is perfectly grammatical and makes sense.

You could try:

> Just following up on our communication a few weeks ago...

Or:

> Further to our communication a few weeks ago...

to make sure they know that you were in touch before, and are re-approaching her to solve something.

You could use '*conversation*' instead of '*communication*' if you want. It's probably a little less formal but it's still okay.

Comment: *Further to our communication...* went out of style at least thirty years ago.

Comment: @Clare - so don't keep it to yourself, share how it's said now!

Comment: @Dan  in any kind of natural  normal unstilted sentence. Like the one in the question title.

Comment: @Clare that's weird - I'm not even 30 yet!